# git subtree push asks to enter passphrase (gpg) 20 times

Tags: git, heroku, gnupg

NOTE: this is not SSH passphrase, it's GPG

I am trying to deploy to heroku through a subdirectory which is called backend

I found online with such command `git subtree push --prefix=backend heroku master git push using:  heroku master`

After using this command, it asks for my passphrase which does happen each time I make a commit  normally to github because I got GPG setup.

But somehow when I do the subtree push to heroku, it asks me to enter the correct passphrase 19 times which I tried then it'll push and try to deploy.  I made those push,  now it's asking me to enter passphrase for 20 times.

this is how it looks

```
1/20 (0)
You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "name <email>"
1234-bit key, ID ACD, created 2020-11-28
```

Does anyone has any idea how I can make it back to enter passphrase only one time?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and advices.

Answer (score 1):

Considering (as [documented here](https://brandur.org/fragments/gpg-heroku)) the Heroku CLI reads and writes to the same `.netrc` format that Curl uses with the [netrc gem](https://github.com/heroku/netrc), check `gpg-agent` is running.

Note: If a `.netrc.gpg` is present, [Heroku will shell out to GPG](https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/29) to read from it the passphrase.

The idea remains: That gem should not request your passphrase if the `gpg-agent` is running ([commit 4ef9562](https://github.com/heroku/netrc/commit/4ef9562482048d9a7eff23313a99dd191f8df719)).
See [gpg-agent](https://brandur.org/dotfile-gpg#gpg-agent) to start it.